# DD Wrt Wifi bridge connection breaking

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dd-wrt, bridge

I have a DD Wrt connected to a DD Wrt router as a Router - Client bridge setup. It works fine for sometime, but occasionally, it appears to stop communicating to the router, or internet.. not sure.

What I see is occasionally my Linux PC looses internet access, and my Win 8 Laptop calls the connection "Limited". Both of these are connected to the client bridge. They can still talk to each other at this point though.

This entire setup worked fine when the Main router was running its default TP Link firmware, so I am thinking this might be wireless setting issue? As far as I can tell, connecting directly to the main router seems fine for the rest of my roommates.

Is there a fix to this? How would I go about diagnosing this? To reiterate, occasionally the connection to the main router fails, and when it fails it stays failed until i restart the bridge router.

Edit: Just checked, sensitivity ack is 200 on main and 0 on bridge, not sure if this might be the culprit.

Comment: You might also have a look at experimenting with [TX Power](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Advanced_wireless_settings#TX_Power). See also [DD-WRT FAQ](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Index:FAQ#How_high_should_I_set_the_transmit_power_on_my_router.3F).

Comment: @harrymc I would have thought that TX Power might lead to a bit more unpredictable situation than this. My case is a stable situation where it works and when it stops, it appears to stay down consistently.

Comment: How long does it stay down? Does it clear up by itself or do you need to power down one or both routers? Why do you use DD-WRT if it causes problems?

Comment: @harrymc It stays down quite long(minutes) but ive not really tested how long. I usually cycle the bridging router, no need to cycle the main router. I used DD Wrt initially to enable the bridge. The 2nd DD wrt was just for kicks, but before this issue was seen. I would like to fix rather than hide from this issue though

Comment: See if there something when [Logging with DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Logging_with_DD-WRT).

Comment: I have increased the Tx power and set the ack to 0, it seems to be holding so far

Comment: This was my guess in the initial comment - that DD-WRT used different defaults for their setting than the original firmware, especially TX Power‌​. This means that the reception is somewhat weak between the two routers. Shall I post an answer for it?

Comment: @harrymc yeah sure, i will accept it, odd why it stops all together though

Comment: This is probably an error condition badly handled by DD-WRT. You could raise it up in their forums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same routers used to work with different firmware, so this is a DD-WRT problem
with using that same hardware.
DD-WRT may use different defaults for their setting than the original firmware
that do not suite the working conditions at your place.

The most significant parameter is [TX Power‌​](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Advanced_wireless_settings#TX_Power) where the default value is 20 (mW) MilliWatts.
This may not be enough if reception conditions are somewhat less than optimal
because of obstacles or interference.

The [DD-WRT FAQ](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Index:FAQ#How_high_should_I_set_the_transmit_power_on_my_router.3F) says this :

> **How high should I set the transmit power on my router?**
>
> Somewhere around 84 mW is considered to be the best setting for
>   maximum power with minimum noise for most hardware. The Buffalo
>   WHR-HP-G54 has a built-in amplifier. The amplifier is turned on by
>   default; the radio power should not be set above 10mW (on v23SP2), or
>   70mW (on v24). The forums have had discussions about what power level
>   is safe, with little consensus. Use common sense and don't set the
>   power higher than you really need to. If you're trying to get more
>   range, consider using a different antenna and make sure you have a
>   clear line of sight, two of the most critical factors in your router's
>   range.
>
> From a network security standpoint, the transmitter power level should
>   be just enough to cover the intended area reliably. Optimal power
>   settings can be determined by trial-and-error.

Comment: Didnt feel like it should be the problem, but bumping it up to 40, i think, has made it a lot more stable, and i have not hit that issue since

Comment: @KarthikT Did you solve your problem by increasing the power of your primary router or of your client bridge? I would infer the former but I wanted to double check.

Comment: @Zeimyth I think router.. but I dont remember, and I dont have this setup any more so i cant check :(